# swc not resolving import path aliases

Tags: typescript, swc, swc-compiler

I have a typescript project which I'm transpiling with swc. I'm having trouble getting swc to resolve path aliases defined in either `tsconfig.json` or `.swcrc`. The module aliases are resolved properly by eslint and when running ts-node when swc is not specified as the compiler.

Given [this pull request](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/pull/1834), it seems that swc is both supposed to resolve `tsconfig.json` and has support for path aliases defined in `.swcrc`. However, it seems people experienced [similar issues to mine](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/702#issuecomment-905571726) following this feature, though it was two years ago and I can't imagine there hasn't been a solution since.

Also on a weird sort of side-note the author of the PR which implements TSConfigResolver that I linked earlier mentions in [an issue a year after his PR was merged](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/4729#issuecomment-1133604100) that swc "doesn't look at tsconfig". Though this shouldn't be the source of my problem though because I'm specifying the same path aliases in `.swcrc`

The swc documentation is horribly vague and doesn't mention anything about module aliases or resolving tsconfig, besides that `jsc.baseUrl` and `jsc.paths` are compilation options and they match tsconfig syntax.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

`.swcrc`

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "jsc": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "es6"
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@swc/cli": "^0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.35",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

I receive the following error when running `swc . -d ./dist` from the project root directory:

`CustomError: Cannot find package '$lib' imported from /root/projects/example/src/index.ts`

Comment: did you have any luck finding an answer to this? I’m experiencing the same issue

Comment: nothing yet unfortunately. I suspect it's a bug with swc's module resolution, or maybe I'm just misusing the config but the docs are not helpful atm. Apparently people have been [experiencing similar issues](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/1858#issuecomment-1012395199) for a long time.


It might be worth a new github issue.

Comment: I experienced a similar issue. I also have my code inside src and transpiling into dist. In my tsconfig.json file im using this config: "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@cli/*": ["./cli/*"],}. In .swcrc on the other side i need to specify the baseUrl where the transpilen code goes to. In my case dist. This gives me following config for .swcrc: "baseUrl": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "@cli/*": ["./cli/*"],}. I hope this helps you in any case.

Comment: https://github.com/swc-project/swc-node/pull/666 apparently tsconfig paths is supported hrm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was fixed in recent pull request.
Make sure you specified your paths in both tsconfig.json and .swcrc
https://github.com/swc-project/swc-node/pull/723

Comment: This helped me. I set `./src` in my `.swcrc` file and then same in `tsconfig.json` ,`"baseUrl": "./src"`. It is workign when I run the app. It shows some terminal erros, but works fine. But If I try to `npm run build`, it fails and throws a large number of error. One of them is `failed to handle: base_dir(`./src`) must be absolute. Please ensure that '`jsc.baseUrl`' is specified correctly. This cannot be deduced by SWC itself because SWC is a transpiler and it does not try to resolve project details. In other works, SWC does not know which directory should be used as a base directory.` Help!.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve `Cannot find module` when building typescript projects with SWC, you will have to add your `baseUrl` and `paths` to your `.swcrc` file as well.

For eg:

tsconfig.json

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "*": ["node_modules", "src/*"]
},
```

This configuration from the `tsconfig.json` file should be also added to your `swcrc` file's `jsc` block.

jwcrc

```
"jsc": {
"parser": {
  "syntax": "typescript"
},
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "*": ["node_modules", "src/*"]
}
},
```